# strpos and mb_strpos is not working in Hindi and Gujarati language php

Tags: php

**Here is my code :**

```
$string = "#ESSAY#जवाहरलाल नेहरू#
शि‍क्षा : जवाहरलाल नेहरू को दुनिया के बेहतरीन स्कूलों और विश्वविद्यालयों में शिक्षा प्राप्त करने का मौका मिला था। उन्होंने अपनी स्कूली शिक्षा हैरो और कॉलेज की शिक्षा ट्रिनिटी कॉलेज, लंदन से पूरी की थी। उन्होंने अपनी लॉ की डिग्री कैम्ब्रिज विश्वविद्यालय से पूरी की।

हैरो और कैम्ब्रिज में पढ़ाई कर 1912 में नेहरूजी ने बार-एट-लॉ की उपाधि ग्रहण की और वे बार में बुलाए गए। पंडित नेहरू शुरू से ही गांधीजी से प्रभावित रहे और 1912 में कांग्रेस से जुड़े। 1920 के प्रतापगढ़ के पहले किसान मोर्चे को संगठित करने का श्रेय उन्हीं को जाता है। 1928 में लखनऊ में साइमन कमीशन के विरोध में नेहरू घायल हुए और 1930 के नमक आंदोलन में गिरफ्तार हुए। उन्होंने 6 माह जेल काटी। 1935 में अलमोड़ा जेल में 'आत्मकथा' लिखी। उन्होंने कुल 9 बार जेल यात्राएं कीं। उन्होंने विश्वभ्रमण किया और अंतरराष्ट्रीय नायक के रूप में पहचाने गए। 
योगदान : उन्होंने 6 बार कांग्रेस अध्यक्ष के पद (लाहौर 1929, लखनऊ 1936, फैजपुर 1937, दिल्ली 1951, हैदराबाद 1953 और कल्याणी 1954) को सुशोभित किया। 1942 के 'भारत छोड़ो' आंदोलन में नेहरूजी 9 अगस्त 1942 को बंबई में गिरफ्तार हुए और अहमदनगर जेल में रहे, जहां से 15 जून 1945 को रिहा किए गए। नेहरू ने पंचशील का सिद्धांत प्रतिपादित किया और 1954 में 'भारतरत्न' से अलंकृत हुए नेहरूजी ने तटस्थ राष्ट्रों को संगठित किया और उनका नेतृत्व किया।

सन् 1947 में भारत को आजादी मिलने पर जब भावी प्रधानमंत्री के लिए कांग्रेस में मतदान हुआ तो सरदार वल्लभभाई पटेल और आचार्य कृपलानी को सर्वाधिक मत मिले थे। किंतु महात्मा गांधी के कहने पर दोनों ने अपना नाम वापस ले लिया और जवाहरलाल नेहरू को प्रधानमंत्री बनाया गया। पंडित जवाहरलाल नेहरू 1947 में स्वतंत्र भारत के पहले प्रधानमंत्री बने। आजादी के पहले गठित अंतरिम सरकार में और आजादी के बाद 1947 में भारत के प्रधानमंत्री बने और 27 मई 1964 को उनके निधन तक इस पद पर बने रहे। 

नेहरू पाकिस्तान और चीन के साथ भारत के संबंधों में सुधार नहीं कर पाए। उन्होंने चीन की तरफ मित्रता का हाथ भी बढ़ाया, लेकिन 1962 में चीन ने धोखे से आक्रमण कर दिया। चीन का आक्रमण जवाहरलाल नेहरू के लिए एक बड़ा झटका था और शायद इसी वजह से उनकी मौत भी हुई। जवाहरलाल नेहरू को 27 मई 1964 को दिल का दौरा पडा़ जिसमें उनकी मृत्यु हो गई।

'स्वाधीनता और स्वाधीनता की लड़ाई को चलाने के लिए की जाने वाली कार्रवाई का खास प्रस्ताव तो करीब-करीब एकमत से पास हो गया। ...खास प्रस्ताव इत्तफाक से 31 दिसंबर की आधी रात के घंटे की चोट के साथ, जबकि पिछला साल गुजरकर उसकी जगह नया साल आ रहा था, मंजूर हुआ।' -लाहौर अधिवेशन में स्वतंत्रता प्रस्ताव पारित होने के बारे में नेहरू की 'मेरी कहानी' से।
उपसंहार : नेहरू के कार्यकाल में लोकतांत्रिक परंपराओं को मजबूत करना, राष्ट्र और संविधान के धर्मनिरपेक्ष चरित्र को स्थायी भाव प्रदान करना और योजनाओं के माध्यम से देश की अर्थव्यवस्था को सुचारु करना उनके मुख्य उद्देश्य रहे।
13. आपका मनपसंद कलर कौन सा है? [first in hindi]
*a. लाल
*b. हरा
*c. पीला
*d. नीला
Ans. D
*difficulty: single
*language: hindi
*exam: hindi sunject
*year: 2017
*rightMark: 3
*wrongMark: 0
*time: 2
#END#";

if (($essayPosition = mb_strpos($string, "#ESSAY#")) !== FALSE) { 
    $whatIWant = "#".extractString($string, "#ESSAY#", "#END#");
    $essayname = extractString($whatIWant, "#", "#");
    echo "Essay Name : ".$essayname;
}

function extractString($string, $start, $end) {
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = mb_strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";

    $ini += mb_strlen($start);
    $len = mb_strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    if($len < 0){
        $len = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return mb_substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

I want to find **जवाहरलाल नेहरू** words from given string but $essayname returns blank values. But when I use **Jawaharlal Nehru** instead of **जवाहरलाल नेहरू** it work's fine for me. Any body guesses how it's possible?

Thank you all in advance. I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: It works for me! What version of PHP are you using

Comment: I'm using PHP 5. Sir may I know what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP5.?.? There quite a few versions of PHP5 and some major difference between PHP5.1 and PHP5.6